# Which Desktop Environment do I have?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, desktop-environment

I have a computer with Arch linux. I want to know which desktop environment is installed.

My ultimate goal would be to install Gnome. Is it possible to have two desktop environments.

Comment: Post a screenshot, if you can find a way to do that.

Comment: It's definitely possible to have multiple desktop environments installed. Even multiple DE running in separate GUI sessions at the same time. But only a single DE in a given GUI session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to print some env variable. At least gnome fill the X environment variable XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP correctly:

```
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```